# Append custom stopwords to default stopwords list from nltk.corpus and remove stopwords from a series in a dataframe using lambda

Tags: python, lambda, tags, flickr, stop-words

i have multicolumn dataframe with 41,000 rows of Flickr tags. I want to remove all the English stopwords from only a column, leaving other columns intact.

this is my code extracting list of stopwords from nltk.corpus:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopWordsListEng = stopwords.words("english")
```

but i want to add additional stopwords that i can think of:

```
according accordingly across act actually
```

i haven't figured out how to add that to the existing list of stopwords.

and how do i apply lambda to remove stopwords in only one column. Because i want my code to be as simple as possible.

here is how my column looks like:

```
column1                        column2                                                 column3
some words from this column    i don't know actually what across to me accordingly     25,000
```

i want my column to look like this (more or less) after i remove all the stopwords:

```
column1                        column2                column3
some words from this column    don't know what to me  25,000
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! What version of Python and NLTK are you using? I'd suggest casting `stopWordsListEng` to a `set` and adding the words to the set.

Comment: hi @hongsy, i use python 3.7.3 and i dont know how to chech what version of NLTK i use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add additional stopwords to existing one using list `extend`

```
_new_stopwords_to_add = ['according', 'accordingly', 'across', 'act', 'actually']
stopWordsListEng.extend(_new_stopwords_to_add)
```

remove stopwords from one pandas column only using [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df['column2'] = df['column2'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([item for item in x.split() if item not in stopWordsListEng]))
```

Comment: how do i do that @Shijith?

Comment: got it @Shijith